# Qt - large quantity widget display without UI freeze

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I want to display a large amount of widgets (~10 thousand) as fast as possible without blocking the UI. The widgets are simple `QPixmap`s containing images loaded from the disk and stored inside a `QVector`.

Here is the problematic code:

```
for (QPixmap image : images) {
    QLabel* label = new QLabel();
    label->setPixmap(image);
    flowLayout->addWidget(label);
}
```

At some point over 5000 thousand images the UI starts to freeze out but then comes back alive.

I have a possible solution with the use of `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`, but that makes the process very slow (although visually elegant).

```
int k = 0;
for (QPixmap image : images) {
    ++k;
    QLabel* label = new QLabel();
    label->setPixmap(image);
    flowLayout->addWidget(label);
    if (k >= 100) {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        k = 0;
    }
}
```

With *k* I am trying to calibrate the UI thread's refresh rate.

So my question is to what is the best approach or is there a good middle ground? One which displays multiple widgets without overwhelming the main thread.

**Side note:** I am doing a kind of a benchmark test which involves large quantity image displaying. A *JavaFX* approach almost instantly spits out the images to the UI from the memory, but I have found it a bit slower in loading and displaying the images. What I mean is that the C++ approach up to some 5000 images works faster in every aspect but problems start occurring after that.

Comment: is your disk fast enough? have you profiled your code? what takes the longest time? constructing QPixmap or constructing QLabel, or setting the pixmap or adding the widget? Also how much performance are you willing to sacrifice to improve your UI response?

Comment: Is your screen actually large enough to show 5000 images?
This amount of data sounds more like a use case for a model/view approach

Comment: @user3528438 I did not profile my code, but clearly adding the widgets takes the longest time. My image loader uses all of the available CPU threads, running them at 100% but when it comes to the GUI's single thread I just don't know what else could be done. Maybe the Qt GUI is not really suited for this kind of task? It seems to me that JavaFX is much more responsive and well built (the displaying process is identical).

Comment: @KevinKrammer Actually the screen size does not matter, because I calculate the available display's size and after I load an image from the hard drive, the image gets resized (and then stored in memory) so that everything will be visible

Comment: QWidgets are likely not the most efficient way to implement this.  You may want to look at using the QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView API instead (in particular the qtbase/examples/widgets/graphicsview/chip example application)

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner, I will look into that